# typedef (alias) vs struct performance?

Tags: c++

Firstly, there are questions about typedef structs vs structs but this is about aliasing, so hopefully it's not a duplicate.

I'm trying to optimize things using SSE2, 4.1, AVX, etc. Is there any difference between this:

```
typedef _m512 Single
```

and:

```
struct Single
{
public:
    Single& operator=(const _m512& InValue);
    operator _m512() const { return Value; }

private:
    _m512 Value;
};
```

Performance wise?

Comment: If it's important to you, measure it.

Comment: `typedef _m512 Single` contains no executable code, so I'm not sure what "performance" you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference in runtime performance between these two compile-time constructs.

They both take zero nanoseconds.